# convert kotlin dsl gradle to groovy build.gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I created a springboot app in Kotlin&gradle with the [initialiser](https://start.spring.io/) but the auto-generated build.gradle file is in kotlin with the extension `build.gralde.kts` (see content below):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.10"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want the project to be in Kotlin but the gradle file to be in `build.gradle` as per old java applications.

Please tell me how to generate a kotlin springboot app with a normal `build.gradle` file or how to covert the generated `build.gradle.kts` into `build.gradle`??

Comment: `build.gradle` file uses `groovy` syntax. refer https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html for reverse syntax conversion

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I dont think there is any method to generate a Kotlin SpringBoot application with a `build.gradle` that is using the groovy DSL. Your best bet will be to convert the gradle file manually, which can take a little time but is pretty easy once you understand/get the hang of it.

I'd reccomend checking out the [Gradle Groovy to Kotlin Conversion](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html) guide made by the Gradle organisation and just do the opposite to all the conversions listed.

And for a more simple example I'd also check out the example posted by the Kotlin organisation on [Converting to Kotlin DSL.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-gradle.html#create-project-files)